# Passing sensitive information to Docker container in AWS EC2 container service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ecs

I am currently learning how to use Docker and Amazon's EC2 Container Service. I have an application that needs access to sensitive information (API keys, database passwords). It doesn't seem appropriate to build this information into the Docker image.

How should I securely store the sensitive information and how can I make it available to my application running in a container?

Answer (score 2):

ECS does not have a built-in feature for secure storage.  However, you can use pretty much any secure storage mechanism with ECS that you can use with EC2.  Common patterns are encrypted data stored in S3 that is downloaded and decrypted by the container when it starts, data encrypted with KMS (either stored in the container or passed in as an environment variable) and decrypted by the container when it starts, and third-party solutions like [HashiCorp's Vault](https://vaultproject.io/).